# SyntaxError in a print statement in library code

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I installed the package of tt-watson but if i run some code i have an error the code is:

```
from tts_watson.TtsWatson import TtsWatson

ttsWatson = TtsWatson("watson_user", "watson_password", "en-US_AllisonVoice") 
ttsWatson.play(str("Hello World"))
```

I'm shown this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "voice.py", line 1, in <module>    
    from tts_watson.TtsWatson import TtsWatson
  File "/home/jesus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tts_watson/TtsWatson.py", line 20
    print "Transform '" + str(text) + "' into sound"   
                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace? This even doesn't include the error type.

Comment: Looking at [the page for tts-watson](https://pypi.org/project/tts-watson/) it clearly states **Python 2.7** as a requirement.

Comment: @Bakuriu the package metadata [is clearly designed for both](https://github.com/gfleetwood/tts-watson/blob/master/setup.cfg), and I don't see the code the stacktrace refers to in [the file](https://github.com/gfleetwood/tts-watson/blob/master/tts_watson/TtsWatson.py#L20) anymore. The OP must have an old version.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I don't think so given that the repo has a couple open issues, [one of which is the same as the OP](https://github.com/gfleetwood/tts-watson/issues/3). The author of this package probably did not correctly set the metadata for the package. Apparently the author [merged a PR for python3 compatibility](https://github.com/gfleetwood/tts-watson/commit/68b3330d1dbb6bcee22ff8fbceb48001c870593d) but the only release is the 2016 one which does not handle python3.

Answer (score 3):

`print` is a function in Python 3, and should be called with parenthesis. I.e., in this case:

```
print("Transform '" + str(text) + "' into sound")
-----^------------------------------------------^
```

It seems as you have installed a Python 2 library (or at least, a version of it that only supports Python 2) and are trying to use it with Python 3.